# "Printing" a numpy array to a PyQT5 QTextEdit

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a method which returns a numpy.ndarry, now I want to print that matrix/array in my GUI which is a QTextEdit box, I tried simply doing:

```
self.textbox.setText(SomeMethod(arg1,arg2)) #numpyarray
```

However my program simply goes into a freeze :( I can't seem to find anyone doing this besides people converting to some Image.. Anyone got any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Try with: `self.textbox.setText(str(SomeMethod(arg1,arg2))) `

Comment: @eyllanesc You're a goddamn genius! Thanks buddy, have a good one!